# What is the utility of escape sequence '\'?

Tags: c

In the below code snippet , how is '\' behaving ?

```
printf("hii\"); // This line gives error :  missing terminating " character

printf("hii\  n"); // This line prints hii n
```

I am unable to get how this escape sequence is behaving here ,Please explain .

Comment: in first line backslash escapes ", thus the missing terminator. In the second line it just escapes one space

Comment: I think you should research what the term "escape sequence" means in this context.

Comment: in the first line don't you see that the string lasts until **after** `terminating "` in a syntax-highlighting editor? That's what the job of the [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence#Programming_languages): allow you to embed special characters in the string, otherwise how do you know the `"` is for terminating the string or just a character you want to print?

Answer (score 2):

An [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) isn't the single `\` character; it's that *followed by another character*. For example, `\"` is an escape sequence, as is `\n`. Under some circumstances you can see more than a single character following the backslash all as the same escape code; this has to do with how the characters are represented internally (ASCII or Unicode value) and can be safely ignored for now.

An escape sequence is used to write a character that is inconvenient/impossible to put into the code directly. For example, `\"` is the escape sequence for a quotation mark. It is like putting a quote inside the string, which you couldn't otherwise do because it would instead close the string literal. Look at the syntax highlighting of your question to see what I mean; most of the first line is considered part of the string, because you never have an *unescaped* closing quote.

The most common escape sequence is perhaps `\n`. Unlike with `\"`, it doesn't just produce a literal `n` in the string; you could do that without an escape. Instead it produces a newline. The code

```
printf("hii\nthere");
```

prints

```
hii
there
```

to the screen.

The second line of code in your question uses the escape sequence `\` (backslash space). Thisis not a standard escape sequence; if you compile with warnings your compiler will probably report that it's ignoring it or something.

(If you want to actually print a backslash to the screen, you need to escape a backslash, using `\\`)

Comment: @3Dave Oops, fixed (the extra `i` is from the question)